# Delete Folders where count>5

Tags: powershell, count, directory, delete-file

I Need some help here: the following script needs to be changed so, that the script delete only Folders in the Subdirectory not Files. Can anyone help me?

```
$path = "C:\test\1"
$keep = 3
$strLogFileName   = "c:\test\yourlogfile.log";

function Log-Message
 {
   Param ([string]$logtext)
   Add-content $strLogFileName -value $logtext
 }

  $dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}
  foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.name -      like "*.zip"}
  if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
    $files | Sort-Object CreationTime -desc| Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | 
    % { $dt=get-date;(Log-Message "Deleting File $_  on  $dt");$_ }| Remove-Item -Force 

  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

My original answer was -WAY- off base, and having RTFQ I've got something that should work for you.

```
function Remove-LargeFolders
{
Param([string]$RootPath)

$keep = 5

#Get a list of the dirs in the first level of the folder
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}

foreach ($dir in $dirs) {

    #Call function on the new folder to check all the sublevels before deleting 
    #the top-level folder.
    Remove-LargeFolders $dir.FullName

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer `
     -and $_.name -like "*.zip"}

    if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
        $dt=get-date
        Log-Message "Deleting Folder $dir  on  $dt"
        $dir

        Remove-Item $dir.FullName -Force -Recurse
        }
}
}
```

This should do what you're looking for. The answer was recursion! Essentially, the script only looks at one level of folders at a time. It digs down to the bottom of each folder tree, before working it's way back up to the top.

This script will work as written, but there is a proviso. Right now, if the script is targeting a structure like this:

```
Target Folder (4 files)
    SubFolder (10 files)
      SubSubFolder (5 files)
```

It will check SubSubFolder first and not delete it, since it has 5 or fewer files. However, once it hops back up to SubFolder, it will see a folder that is too big and kill it off, getting rid of SubSubFolder in the process. If you want a way around that, you'll need to build in some checks that will allow you to see if each folder has another folder in it before deleting.

Hope this helps more!

Comment: Hello,

first thank you for your effort. I want to keep only the last 5  in the archive and the rest should sorted by date and delete the oldest.
 
Example in the archive `\\xxxx\yyy\vvvv\DWH\pu_207\archive\  are 6 Forders:20130101,20130102,20130103,20130104,20130105,20130106`

only deletes the folder 20130101 because it is the oldest. The rest should stay and then applies to all other archives like the following:`\\xxxx\yyy\vvvv\DWH\pu_208\archive\20130101` and sorry for my bad english. Thx